# Apache tika and apache ctakes

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu

```
~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_212"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b10, mixed mode)

~$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T22:11:47+05:30)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_212, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.13.0-37-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

apache tika 1.23
apache ctakes 3.2.2
ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I have followed the steps on [the official site](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/CTAKESParser).

while the step

```
java -classpath $HOME/src/ctakes-config:${TIKA_HOME}/tika-app/target/tika-app-X.Y-SNAPSHOT.jar:${CTAKES_HOME}/desc:${CTAKES_HOME}/resources:${CTAKES_HOME}/lib/\* org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI --config=$HOME/src/ctakes-config/tika-config.xml -m Vose-2013-American_Journal_of_Hematology.pdf
```

I am getting this error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI

please help

Comment: Do you have TIKA_HOME, CTAKES_HOME variables set?

Comment: u are right i did not set TIKA_HOME, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably you did not set the variables `TIKA_HOME` and/or `CTAKES_HOME` in the environment you want to run the command.